# How can i make the configure file search for a library in particular directory

Tags: linux, makefile, build, configure, autotools

I am trying to build the `arp-scan` tool from source.When i first tried it was missing the library `libpcap`. So i downloaded the libcap source and build the source successfully.Now i have the library `libpcap.so.1.5.3` locally in a directory `/tmp/Abhiszg/libpcap-1.5.3`. So now how can i tell the `configure` file of `arp-scan` look for `libpcap` at `/tmp/Abhiszg/libpcap-1.5.3`.

## Configuration and build details

---

This is how compiled and installed libpcap

`./configure --prefix=/tmp/Abhie5l/lib`

`make && make install`

this is how my `/tmp/Abhie5l/lib` looks like

```
bin
|  pcap-config
|
include
|--pcap
|    bluetooth.h
|    bpf.h
|    ...
|
|  pcap-bpf.h
|  pcap.h
|  ...
|
lib
|  libpcap.a
|  libpcap.so
|  libpcap.so.1
|  libpcap.so.1.11.0-PRE-GIT
|--pkgconfig
|    libpcap.pc
|
man
|--man
|----man1
|----man2
|    ...
```

##### Configuration of `arp-scan`

---

When i looked into the `./configure --help` of `arp-scan` it has mentioned about these environmental variables.

> Some influential environment variables:
>
> CC   C compiler command
>
> CFLAGS   C compiler flags
>
> LDFLAGS   linker flags, e.g. -L if you have libraries
> in a nonstandard directory <lib dir>
>
> LIBS    libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
>
> CPPFLAGS   (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I if you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>

So I change my configuration command like this, 
`./configure LDFLAGS=/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/ LIBS=-llibpcap.so`

But i got this error

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

This is my config.log file,

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by arp-scan configure 1.10.1-git, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.71.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure LDFLAGS=/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/ LIBS=-llibpcap.so

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = IN-1534
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.19.0-35-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/abhijithea/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/.local/bin/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/.local/bin/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/.cargo/bin/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/.local/bin/
PATH: /usr/local/sbin/
PATH: /usr/local/bin/
PATH: /usr/sbin/
PATH: /usr/bin/
PATH: /sbin/
PATH: /bin/
PATH: /usr/games/
PATH: /usr/local/games/
PATH: /snap/bin/
PATH: /snap/bin/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/Android/Sdk/emulator/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
PATH: /home/abhijithea/apps/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2419: looking for aux files: compile config.guess config.sub missing install-sh
configure:2432:  trying ./build-aux/
configure:2461:   ./build-aux/compile found
configure:2461:   ./build-aux/config.guess found
configure:2461:   ./build-aux/config.sub found
configure:2461:   ./build-aux/missing found
configure:2443:   ./build-aux/install-sh found
configure:2593: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2666: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2677: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2732: result: yes
configure:2891: checking for a race-free mkdir -p
configure:2935: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2942: checking for gawk
configure:2977: result: no
configure:2942: checking for mawk
configure:2963: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2974: result: mawk
configure:2985: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3008: result: yes
configure:3038: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3056: result: yes
configure:3202: checking build system type
configure:3217: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3237: checking host system type
configure:3251: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3275: checking if gcov code coverage is enabled
configure:3292: result: no
configure:3299: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:3369: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:3436: checking for gcc
configure:3457: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3468: result: gcc
configure:3821: checking for C compiler version
configure:3830: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3841: $? = 0
configure:3830: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
... rest of stderr output deleted ...
configure:3841: $? = 0
configure:3830: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3841: $? = 1
configure:3830: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3841: $? = 1
configure:3830: gcc -version >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-version'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3841: $? = 1
configure:3861: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3883: gcc   /tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/ conftest.c -llibpcap.so >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/: file format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpcap.so: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3887: $? = 1
configure:3927: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "arp-scan"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "arp-scan"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.10.1-git"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "arp-scan 1.10.1-git"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "arp-scan"
| #define VERSION "1.10.1-git"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main (void)
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3932: error: in `/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan':
configure:3934: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=-llibpcap.so
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} '\''/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/missing'\'' aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} '\''/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/missing'\'' autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} '\''/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/missing'\'' autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} '\''/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/missing'\'' automake-1.16'
AWK='mawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CSCOPE='cscope'
CTAGS='ctags'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
ETAGS='etags'
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS='/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS='-llibpcap.so'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} '\''/tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/missing'\'' makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='arp-scan'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan'
PACKAGE_NAME='arp-scan'
PACKAGE_STRING='arp-scan 1.10.1-git'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='arp-scan'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.10.1-git'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='1.10.1-git'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /tmp/Abhie5l/arp-scan/build-aux/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "arp-scan"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "arp-scan"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.10.1-git"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "arp-scan 1.10.1-git"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "arp-scan"
#define VERSION "1.10.1-git"

configure: exit 77
```

### Note:

Before the update the directory was `/tmp/Abhiszg` and in the update i specified the directory `/tmp/Abhie5l/` that's because i was testing it in temporary directory.

## Latest update

---

Now i successfully built the `arp-scan`,

`./configure LDFLAGS=-L/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/lib/ LIBS=-l:libpcap.so CFLAGS=-I/tmp/Abhie5l/lib/include/`

But now when i run it `./arp-scan` it's showing an error like this,

```
./arp-scan: error while loading shared libraries: libpcap.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i think it is not able to find the library in runtime. anyone have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: what was the link you used to get the src? Did you look in the `arp-scan` ./configure and makefile files to see where it expects to find that library? Good luck.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should install libpcap to the system by running `sudo make install` in its build directory.  Unless you requested a different location at its configuration time, it will probably be installed in /usr/local/lib, where it will be easier to find.

Comment: But as to how to find it in a non-default location, the first thing to do is run `./configure --help` in arp-scan's build folder.  There may be configuration options that will help.

Comment: Note also that if you are using the shared-library version of libpcap, then you need to be able to find it not only at build time, but also at *run* time.  Which is all the more reason to avoid putting it in a directory outside the default library search path.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes i have look at `./configure --help` and there is there is a options for specifying the library path and library name but when run the conffiguration file i am gettting this error. i will update my question

Comment: @shellter I have looked into the `configure` file it has environmental variables to specify the library path and library name. but when i give the name i am getting some errors. i have updated my question with errors

Comment: @JohnBollinger i have successfully built the `arp-scanp` but now i am getting an error ```./arp-scan: error while loading shared libraries: libpcap.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory``` i think it couldn't find the library when it's running which you mentioned that it might happen. Do you know how can i solve it

Comment: @JohnBollinger I fixed the issue it's working now. I just had to add the library path to linker runtime search path.